# Hyper Threading: nosmt in grub configuration

Tags: linux-kernel, kvm, hyperthreading

Currently, I have running Debian 12 instance on dedicate CPU cloud environment. It has 2 cores, 4 threads.
It is not impossible to turn off hyper threading via BIOS settings.

I found possibility to disable hyper threading via system setting in grub in `/etc/default/grub` adding 'nosmt':

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet nosmt"`

I'm wondering is this something like good in terms of performance without hyper threading?
I mean, will disabling it via system settings give the same effectiveness as disabling it via BIOS?

Or it bad idea to make it in that way and it is better to keep hyper threading off in this case (virtual dedicated CPU)?